# Is this connection string for SQL Server 2012 correct?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have this connection string, and I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeName" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MCA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SomeName; Integrated Security=true; ID=sa;Password=testtesttest;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Before this I was making the connection with Windows Authentication, and this connection string worked for me:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeName" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MCA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SomeName; Integrated Security=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I checked https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/ but still I think that my connection string is incorrect :)

Comment: Does it work? We can't tell you if it is right or not. I can tell that syntactically it looks fine. Logically it looks a little weird since you Integrated Security AND user credentials.

Comment: @SeanLange i removed  Integrated Security but still is have problems :)

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct - it might just not do what you think it does....

The problem is that you're specifying **both** `Integrated Security=true;` (which uses built-in Windows authentication) as well as `ID=sa;Password=testtesttest;` (using a SQL Server user account) at the same time.

In this case, the **Integrated Security** wins - your SQL Server authentication isn't even looked at.

If you want to use the specific user and password - remove the `Integrated Security=true;` from your connection string (and I believe it has to be `User ID` - not just `ID`...) :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeName" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MCA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SomeName; User ID=sa;Password=testtesttest;" />
</connectionStrings>
```